# How to get the actual error from express instead of status 500 in React on failed fetch in POST method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a fetch using post method in react component that triggers a database update from ExpressJs server. On failure to database update I get the correct error message in Express console, but In react I get the 500 status error message only. Instead of this 500 status message how can I get the actual error message that available in the express?

My react fetch is as

```
fetch('http://expressurl:5000/updatedb', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ dataToBeupdatedInDb }),
})
.then( response =>  {
    response.json()
    console.log("Can I expect the actual error here : ", response)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log("Or can I expect the actual error here : ", error)
});
```

Express has the apt.post to database as

```
app.post('/updatedb', (req, res) => {
    dbUpdateMethod(req.body)
    .then(response => {
        res.status(200).json(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("The actual error", error) //how can I get this error in React fetch
        res.status(500).send(error);
    })
})
```

Comment: what does this console log gives you ?
.catch(error => {
    console.log("Or can I expect the actual error here : ", error)
});

Comment: @Pritesh instead of the console log I get ‘error 500 internal server error’. Console log is not printing. But if read the error from express I get the correct cause of error and if I rectify accordingly the 500 error vanishes and correct update happens (eg error from express ‘server not accepting ssl connection)

Comment: Always check `response.ok` before attempting to use `response.json()`. You can get the response text by calling `response.text()` which returns a promise resolving with the response body as plain text

Comment: You could maybe try this npm module,. https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-error

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a lot of good advice in this post - [Fetch: reject promise and catch the error if status is not OK?](http://Fetch:%20reject%20promise%20and%20catch%20the%20error%20if%20status%20is%20not%20OK?)

However, I don't see anything dealing with the actual response body so here's how I generally get things working (in an `async` function because IMO the syntax is much nicer)

```js
async function fancyFetch() {
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    // init
  })

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${response.status} ${response.statusText}: ${await response.text()}`)
  }

  return res.json()
}
```

This will return a promise that resolves with the JSON or rejects with either a network-level error (from a failed `fetch()`) or the HTTP error containing the response status and body.

---

The non `async / await` version would look something like

```js
fetch(url, {
  // init
}).then(res => {
  if (!res.ok) {
    return res.text()
      .then(error => Promise.reject(new Error(`${response.status} ${response.statusText}: ${error}`))
  }

  return res.json()
})
```

Comment: Thanks Phil .. I will try this and update here

Comment: I used the async / await as you mentioned and it returned the error but not the one from the express js,  instead it showed "Error: 500 Internal Server Error". But the actual error was from the express "The server does not support SSL connections". Then I toggled back the ssl: true to false to rectify the error.

Comment: thanks for this answer by passing a stringfied error object from the express i was able to get the desired response .. I added my finding as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 0):

We can pass a stringified error object from the express as part of the error response. From the fetch method of the react component check if the response status is true as mentioned in the Phil's answer and thus we can get the error in the console

Fetch post from the react can be as follows

```
async function saveData (dataToBeupdatedInDb) {
    const res = await fetch('http://expressurl:5000/updatedb', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ dataToBeupdatedInDb }),
        })
        if (!res.ok) {
             throw new Error(`${res.status} ${res.statusText}: ${await res.text()}`)
        }
    return res.json()
}
```

This above react code will help to get the status response to the frontend but still the original error thrown from the express will not be displayed in the react side. To get that error edit the following from the express app.post as

```
app.post('/updatedb', (req, res) => {
    dbUpdateMethod(req.body)
    .then(response => {
        res.status(200).json(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        let customError = JSON.stringify(error, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error)) //this will create a stringified error object
        res.status(400).send(customError); //pass the stringified object as part of error response
    })
})
```